# URL masking where files stored inside a sub folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite the URL to "`http://localhost/Test/Mag/magazine/1`"
and it's rewriting the URL but the content of the page is not showing.  Sometimes it's showing 404 error
"Not Found
The requested URL /Test/Mag/magazine/1 was not found on this server." instead.

I'm using an .htaccess file with the following code and the .htaccess file is located on localhost/Test

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^magazine/([0-9]+)$ magazine.php?m=$1
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: What operating system are using and what is file structure like

Comment: Hi @Shubham.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  I noticed that you got downvoted.  One reason might be that it's a little difficult to answer this question because it's missing some details that we need to be able to provide an answer.  For example, just a couple things I can think of are that we need to know what the URL that you're starting with is and what the folder structure is.  Without that information, we can't tell what it's supposed to be doing or see where your problem might be.  Can you please update your question to include some more of those details?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but from your question the server root is localhost and you have folder/directory called Test called in there in which you have the file `magazine.php`, if that's the case then your htaccess should be like so

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Test/

RewriteRule ^magazine/([0-9]+)$ magazine.php?m=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: @Shubham what operating system are using and what is folder/directory like because am working on assumptions, you need to help me help you

Comment: actually before upload im am using Windows 10 but i use linux hosting as hosting space

Comment: Im using wamp server as my local server where in side www i have my main project named as Test within that folder i have a page named as magazine.php where i select a magazine and it open a new tab with file name magazine.php which stored inside "C:\wamp\www\Test\Magazine\magazine.php" im using get method to pass tha value for showing magazine on that file. I want to rewrite the url when someone open that link instead of showing "http://localhost/Nibvarnica/Magazine/magazine.php?m_id=1" i want to show "http://localhost/Nibvarnica/Magazine/magazine/1" is it possible